# Cross domain request nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, cross-domain

Есть cross dimain request, с сайта http://cluster.vk.araneum.dev/ на сайт http://aggregator.vk.araneum.dev.

В браузере ошибка:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://aggregator.vk.araneum.dev/getWidget/ultratrade.
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Origin 'http://cluster.vk.araneum.dev' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> The response had HTTP status code 404.

Настройки nginx (http://aggregator.vk.araneum.dev):

```
location / {
    root  /var/www/aggregator.araneum.dev/source/web;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    autoindex on;
    index  app_dev.php;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' *;
}
```

JS код:

```
$.ajax({
    url: platformDomain+'/getWidget/ultratrade',
    success: function(responce) {
        $('#ultratrade-widget').html(responce.widgetHtml);
    }
});
```

Объясните что я делаю не так

Answer (score 1):

В диективе http добавляем

```
map $http_origin $cors_header {
    default "";
    "~^https?://[^/]+\.vk\.araneum\.dev/?$" "$http_origin";
}
```

В директиве server aggregator.vk.araneum.dev добавляем

```
add_header      Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors_header;
```